# Eliminar caracteres raros en java como ï¿½, �, Ã al tener letra Ñ y acentos

Tags: java, linux

espero y me puedan ayudar, como puedo trabajar con las Ñ en lenguaje java en un servidor linux, lo que pasa es que estoy procesando archivos de texto y en la cual me salen caracteres como los siguientes:�, ?, Ã, ï¿½, ya sea también en algunas ocasiones para los acentos, tengo esto en codigo:

```
public static ArchivoCPBES leerLayoutCPBES(String directorioNombreArchivo, String nombreArchivo, String correos, int limiteErrores)
            throws IOException, PatternSyntaxException, CpagoTBException {
        DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("############.###");
         formateador.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        ArchivoCPBES archivo = new ArchivoCPBES();
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
//      OBJETO QUE ALMACENA LOS ERRORES PRESENTADOS EN EL LAYOUT
        try {
            // Obtenciï¿½n de archivo
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(directorioNombreArchivo);
            // Apertura de archivo
            DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(fileInput);
            //buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput));        
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput, "ISO-8859-1"));
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
            String error="";
            String linea = "";
            int lineas = 0;
            boolean continuarLeyendo = true;
            List<LayoutCPBES> lstCompPago = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
            List<LayoutCPBES> lstCPCuentasIOT = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
            LayoutCPBES layoutCPBES = new LayoutCPBES();
            ComplementoPagoBES cPago = new ComplementoPagoBES();
            // Bucle de lectura de archivo data stage
            while ((linea = buffer.readLine()) != null && continuarLeyendo) {
                error="";
                cPago = new ComplementoPagoBES();
                String separador = Pattern.quote("|");              
                byte [] parameterByte = linea.getBytes(isr.getEncoding());        
                linea = new String(parameterByte, "ISO-8859-1");
                String[] parts = linea.split(separador);
        
                
                lineas++;
```

Pero no me está funcionando, Particularmente es en estas lineas:

```
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput, "ISO-8859-1"));
linea = new String(parameterByte, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor ya que esto algo que nunca he trabajo como ejemplo de la cual están saliendo sería así:
Calle  Col. M�xico Norte, M�rida, Yucat�n

Quedo al pendiente de sus valiosos comentarios y si algo no se entiende con gusto lo explicaré a detalle. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Debe ser por la codificación del archivo y la que estás utilizando para leer (ISO-8859-1).

Si sabes la codificación del archivo, asegúrate de indicar la misma en tu código. Aquí precisamente:

```
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Si no la sabes, abre el archivo con un editor de texto o código que te lo diga, por ejemplo Visual Studio Code.

Es probable que la codificación correcta sea UTF-8.

Comment: Hola Mateo, ya revisé con un editor y me sale como "codificar en ANSI" lo intenté a cambiar a ANSI pero me marca error en el codigo, como se lo podría cambiar para que lo detecte bien? Lo dejé así buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput, "ANSI"));

Comment: @cratus666jose en [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) figura como **US-ASCII**. Puedes obtener la lista completa con [availableCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets--).

Comment: Hola Mateo, entonces sería algo así: buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput, "US-ASCII")); ? Intenté con el de ISO-8859-1 y UTF-8 pero me sigue cambiando los caracteres a raros :(

Comment: @cratus666jose no puedes cambiar la codificación del archivo a UTF-8 y probar con UTF-8 en el código? Visual Studio Code permite cambiar la codificación de los archivos.

Comment: Hola Mateo, buenos días, ya logré arreglar el archivo y ya no salen mal, solo que pasó algo raro, en la bd que es de Oracle y uso el developer se poblaron mal y salieron estos simbolos al hacer las inserciones: Ã, sabes a que se debe este problema?

Comment: @cratus sé poco de base de datos. Si tienes una pregunta sobre eso hazla y alguien que sepa te responderá